# c# - Monitoring Email Activities of pc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

I want to develop an application in wpf which monitors Email activities from my computer.

e.g. After sending mail mail from my yahoo account from browser .. i want to show mail details like sender id , subject etc in datagrid in my WPF application.

Is it possible in wpf C#? How to do that?

Comment: That's not really an email activity" from your computer. It is an email activity from the web-server.

Comment: while not beeing impossible this will be almost uselsess because you would have to parse the communication to yahoo's services (that could change anytime) - and then there are things like SSL to think about. And BTW: WPF will not help nor hinder you in any way - it's a completly different concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

However you need to integrate API's of the application you want to use.

For yahoo, check this
http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/

For gmail you can find on google.

What you need to do is there are 2 ways

1. Either develop a screen in WPF that will let user send mail using your app
2. Access API's to get the data from there Yahoo Server or Gmail Server